# Differences between Folder.fetch and getmessages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to write an app that get emails from a POP3 server. The "Strategy" I used eventually is:

1. Get single message
2. check if the message is already present in my database
3. if not, insert it, goto 1

I know that this is not perfect, but ok...let's just face a problem at once :)

apologizing for the ugly style, I'm well trained as Assembly and pure C programmer, just started with Java, my code to get the single message is (I have cut the try/catch statements to make it more readable)

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = null;
POP3Folder folder = null;
openStaffLabel: {
    store = session.getStore(exXContainer.accounts[selectedAccount].accountType.toLowerCase());
    store.connect(host, username, password);
    folder =(POP3Folder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    int countMsg  = 0;
    countMsg = folder.getMessageCount();
    if (countMsg == 0)
        break openStaffLabel;
    message = folder.getMessages(countMsg - first + 1);
    for(int i = 0;i < messages.length;i++)
    {
        // do some stuffs with messages
    }
} // openStaffLabel:
folder.close(false);
store.close();
```

That seems to work fine. Then I found over internet this code ([here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3092171/JavaMail-More-Efficiently.htm)), claimed by the poster to be much more efficient:

```java
URLName url = new URLName("pop3", host, 110, "", user, password);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(),null);
Store store = session.getStore(url);
store.connect();
POP3Folder inbox = (POP3Folder)store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
profile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
inbox.fetch(messages,profile);
for(int i = 0;i < messages.length;i++)
{
   // do some stuffs with messages
}
```

The author claims: "The major difference with the previous scenario is that the client downloads new emails only"

but in his code there is a inbox.getMessages() that, if I understood well, actually download all messages. So the point is...what is the real advantage of using fetch(messages,profile) if with getMessages I have already fetched all the headers?
if I only want to download UIDs, how can I do?

and, furthermore, if I only want to download the UIDs of the first N mails...is it possible?

thank you very much to anyone who will help, I'm stuck on this problem since one week.
Cristiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP3 isn't the best protocol for this, and you'll understand this better if you understand what the POP3 protocol is capable of doing.

The use of the fetch method that you describe will fetch all the UIDs for all the messages in the mailbox in one operation.  If you keep track of which UIDs you've seen, you can then make sure you only fetch the content of the messages that you haven't seen.  Use the POP3Folder.getUID method in the loop over all the messages to skip the messages you've already seen.  Note that the getMessage methods don't actually fetch the content of the message; the content isn't fetched until you use another method that accesses the content.

Note that the POP3 protocol only lets you fetch the UID for a single message, or the UIDs for all the messages.

Be sure to read the javadocs for the [com.sun.mail.pop3 package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html), and the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html), especially this item about [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thank you very much Bill, maybe I'm starting understand how it works now!. So, I know now that getMessages does not fetch, and this is good so...if fetch actually fetch just the messages got from getMessages, using messages = getMessages(start, end) and then POP3Folder.fetch(messages, profile) I probably can only fetch the UIDs I want...agree?

Comment: Ok, I can answer my self. Tried it and it work brilliantly: `FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
                profile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
                message = folder.getMessages(countMsg - first + 2 - howMany, countMsg - first + 1);
                folder.fetch(message, profile);` only fetches the UID of the messages from 1 to 5. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: It may look like it's only fetching the UIDs for the first 5 messages, but if you look at the protocol trace you'll see that it's fetching the UIDs for all messages.  If there's a lot of messages in the mailbox and you only need the UIDs for a few, that may not be the best approach.

Comment: Sorry for being so late in answer. I have not been able to find a protocol tracer for android (is a mobile app), but actually looking at butes download it seems you are right. As I have to use POP3 (is one of the base-spec of the app), is there a better way to proceed? you wrote in your answer that "POP3 protocol only lets you fetch the UID for a single message, or the UIDs for all the messages"...but, can I fetch the UID of the single message I want, even the numer 100, or just the one of the last received?

Comment: JavaMail protocol trace is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  You can fetch the UID for any message individually, but each request will be a separate interaction with the server.  If you fetch a lot that way, it will be slow.  You'll need to test it to determine if fetching 100, one by one, is too slow.

Comment: thank you very much again for answer and for protocol tracer, that will be really usefull! I finally reached a good solution that looks to work brilliantly with your suggestion!